# Add some other flag explanation to review tasks.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing, review, flagging

Sometimes I want to flag a low quality **answers** which are a short comment or something (not a thank you comment) but I can't find any appropriate explanation in radio buttons so I choose "No comment needed."

[image]

In addition there are some low quality **question** which are not compatible with any of radio buttons, so I prefer to skip these posts rather than report them. I suggest to add or change some explanations based on users similar experiences.

I think the usual flags (not in review task, but in original page of posts) are better and less confusing.

[image]

I suggest that the moderator post a question and ask users to contribute to adapt these explanation.

Comment: More often than not I post a Comment with my own wording on these Questions.  The "template" comments cannot be expected to provide the best advice to users in all situations, only to cover some common situations.  After posting a custom Comment, then the "No Comment" option is appropriate (meaning no additional "template" comment is needed).

Comment: It is possible to add a custom Comment *after* voting to close (from Review).  Use the browser's "back" button, and you will see how the Review item looks after your vote.  A Comment can still be added from that page, and hitting the Next button on the page at upper right will continue to the next Review item in that queue (if any).

Comment: @hardmath Why this must be so hard? I suggested to make it more user friendly if you want get better feedback.

Comment: The items shown next to *flagging* options are not Comment templates and will not appear to users whose posts are flagged.  Some flags are handled by Moderators (and there is a text box to explain your flag when asking for Moderator attention), but others are handled through the Review queues.  I was responding to your dissatisfaction with the (necessarily limited number of) standardized Comment templates, assuming you want to be "give better feedback".  It seems to me that skipping a Review item because you don't like how the optional Comment templates apply to that item misses the point.

Comment: Let me mention one other approach to leaving a Comment for users when you vote to close (or otherwise participate in the Review).  The standarized Comment template leaves a Comment which you can then Edit.  Use the browser "back" function as already described, but instead of leaving a new Comment, you can click to edit the Comment left (under your username) from the standardized template.  This might make the feedback more precise.